# Create the same table(s) on two different declarative bases using SQLAlchemy and Alembic migrations

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have two SQLite databases, say `X` and `Y`. `Y` contains a subset of the tables in `X`. I manage the databases and their data in Python using SQLAlchemy, Alembic and FastAPI. This means that I have two declarative bases, called `BaseX` and `BaseY` respectively. For simplicity, I have two tables I want to create, `TableW` and `TableZ`, where `TableW` should exist in both databases, and `TableZ` solely in `X`. Furthermore, `TableZ` has a foreign key to `TableW`.

Ignoring the foreign key, the model for `TableZ` looks as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column

from app.db.base_class import BaseX


class TableZ(BaseX):
    id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = mapped_column(String)
```

Everything works fine for `TableZ`. Alembic recognizes `TableZ` on `BaseX` and creates it accordingly in the migration for `X`. Since `TableW` exists in both `X` and `Y` (in the exact same form, ignoring the foreign key), I figured it would be most efficient to create a generic class that can be used with both `BaseX` and `BaseY`, so that's where my `TableW` model comes into play:

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column


class GenericTableW:
    def __init__(self, base):
        class TableW(base):
            id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
            name = mapped_column(String)

        self.Model = TableW
```

My approach was to use this in the following way to create `TableW` in `X` (which will be the same for `Y`, using `BaseY`):

```
from app.models.table_w import GenericTableW

from app.db.base_class import BaseX

class TableWInX(GenericTableW):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(base=BaseX)
```

However, Alembic is unable to find and include `TableWInX` in the migration...

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a `TableWInX` class that inherits `TableW`, use this:

```
from app.models.table_w import GenericTableW

from app.db.base_class import BaseX

TableWInX = GenericTableW(BaseX)
```

This way Alembic is able to include `TableW` in `X` in the migration via `TableWInX`. Still unsure why my initial approach did not work though, so if anyone knows the answer to that, feel free to comment!